# Event Listeners in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, events, event-handling

I have a `TestController` scoped session. It's handling `MyEvent`.

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
@Slf4j
public class TestController {

    private String phone = getPhone();

    private String getPhone() {
        String phone = RandomGenerator.generateNumeric(4);
        log.info("Phone is: {}", phone);
        return phone;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void listen(MyEvent event) {
        log.info("Event in {} ({})", this, RandomGenerator.generateNumeric());
    }

}
```

But when I publish the event, only one of instances of the TestController class are getting this. But I want to handle an event in all of the instances. Could you help me?

Comment: All instance of what? You asked for session scope so it's going to publish the event for the current session ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring the `@Controller` with `@Scope("session")`, so you get a new controller bean for each session.

Then, in an undisclosed part of the code you publish an event, so it is reasonable that only the controllers within the same session as the publisher receive the event, because the other controllers are on other sessions.

Therefore, since you have **one** controller per session, the event is only consumed **once**.

The solution is to change the scope from `session` to `singleton` (default) and not to store state in the controller (that phone number).